# Error with floating and rounding down?

Tags: php

I am trying to calculate this in PHP:

```
echo (int)((0.1 + 0.7) * 20);
```

**Why it return:** 15

**Expected result:** 16

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it. It returns 18 for me.

Comment: It also works for me. Is your posted code the exact code you're running?

Comment: Sorry, wrong numbers. Fixed.

Comment: @MarekMarkovič:See the big warning on this page:  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: The answer linked by @JohnConde has everything you need to know

Comment: @AmalMurali Warnings don't get any bigger than that :)

Comment: @AmalMurali It even uses almost the exact same calculation as OP for the example...

Comment: @BadHorsie: Yep. I think it's time for http://www.xkcd.com/217/